# how to swap the value of two variables without an auxilary (helping) variable

Tags: ds.algorithms

how to swap the value of two variables without an auxilary (helping) variable ?

swap(int *x,int *y)
{
  int h = *x; 
  *x = *y; 
  *y = h; 
}

how can we do it without introducing h?

Comment: This is not a research-level question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is using XOR as following:

\begin{eqnarray}
*x = (*x)\wedge(*y);\tag{1}\\
*y = (*x)\wedge(*y);\tag{2}\\
*x = (*x)\wedge(*y)\tag{3};
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Please don't answer such questions. Doing so invites more questions which are not suitable for this forum.

Comment: Knowing how to do this while knowing not much else about programming can be harmful. Many years ago when I was a 2nd year student coding for a huge project as a summer job, I made a C macro for swapping based on the above. Since swap dominated the computation, there was a non-negligible blowout in code size after macro expansion and performance penalty, puzzling the senior members of the team – until they saw my macro.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it is not type-safe. This solution implicitly assumes that there is some encoding of $x, y$ as bits. As far as I know, there is no general type-safe method of swapping two values. (Although some programming languages contain a special command to swap elements).

Comment: Also, note that when $x = y$ this command sets \*x = \*y = 0. You *need* to check if x = y as a special case.

Comment: @DavidHarris You are right, nevertheless it can be fixed: *x = *x + *y; *y = *x - *y; *x = *x - *y; (for ints only).

Comment: @maldini.ua That still suffers from aliasing - you will end up setting *x and *y to 0

Comment: @KlausDraeger Oops, disregard my comment. I had something different in my mind. =(